# HTML5 2 menus within nav

Tags: html, nav

I was wondering if I could draw on your expertise of HTML5.

I have two menus of internal links, one below another. Should I wrap both menus inside one `<nav>` or should each menu be inside it's own `<nav>`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [HTML 5 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/Overview.html#the-nav-element), `<nav>` is defined as:

> The nav element represents a section of a page that links to other
>   pages or to parts within the page: a section with navigation links.
>   Not all groups of links on a page need to be in a nav element only
>   sections that consist of major navigation blocks are appropriate for
>   the nav element. In particular, it is common for footers to have a
>   list of links to various key parts of a site, but the footer element
>   is more appropriate in such cases, and no nav element is necessary for
>   those links.

So `<nav>`, being block-level-element, should have nested `list-items` to make as many as navigation elements you want rather than defining the `<nav>` tag all time to make your navigation.

For Instance,

```
<nav>
<h1>Title</h1>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Item 01</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 02</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 03</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

And by CSS, customize the `lists` to your needs to make it behave the way you want.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Nathan. So would two unordered lists inside a nav be acceptable?

Comment: As with one UL, you can create multiple list as your links, so any specific purpose for 2 ul's - @DesignSubway